# How to break line into jsonb array element?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table:

```
create table table_name 
(id varchar(255), details jsonb)
```

Then i need to update some array into "details"

```
update table_name
set details = '["firstLineSecondLine", "ThirdLineFourthLine"]'::jsonb
where id = '1';
```

How can i break lines between "firstLineSecondLine"?

I need thst my body be like:

```
"details": [
        "firstLine
         SecondLine",
        "ThirdLine
         FourthLine"
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That exact output not going to happen using `jsonb` as it does not preserve white space. You would need to use `json`. To break up the lines enter them as separate elements in the array. Pretty sure `"firstLineSecondLine"`, etc are dummy values, without the actual values it is not possible to determine if the values can be split otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

literal newlines inside quotes in JSON are represented by `\n`.  They are represented this way both on input and on output, so you will not able to get it to show up the way you want to other than converting to plain text, or something else.

Also, your example is invalid for another reason, it is lacking the outer curlies.